# Iterate throw a list of files on python with OS libray

Tags: python, loops, operating-system

I need to iterate throw the files in a folder that contains .doc documments whit a speccific format name, so i need some key values from the names, but the problem is that i can´t iterate throw them like if them where a string. i am using:`os.path.splitext(ruta)`  but it returns none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os library has walk() function.

```
import os

dir = "sample_path"
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir):
    
    for filename in filenames:
        # filename is a string.
        # perform your format matching.
        if "some_key_str" in filename and filename.endswith(".doc"):    # example
            pass
```